# Not equal operator not working with _id in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do a simple filtering of Users so that returned array of users does not contain logged in user, whose `_id` I have. I tried both passing `string` or `ObjectId` value to `$ne` field but that filter is simply not applied. I am sure that i am passing correct `_id`. Why this does not work?

```js
Query: {
    users: async (parent, { limit = 10 }, { models, me }) => {
      const filter = me
        ? { _id: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(me.id) } }
        : {};
      return await models.User.find(filter, null, {
        limit,
      });
},
```

`me` value:

```js
{
  id: '5e36eb8232c4082080f8288a',
  email: 'email0@email.com',
  username: 'user0',
  role: 'ADMIN',
  iat: 1580657981,
  exp: 1580675981
}
```

Users collection sample:

```js
[
  {
    followersIds: [
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e7,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968ea,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968ed,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968f0,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968f3,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968f6,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968f9,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968fc,
      5e36ffe2c1d67534241968ff
    ],
    followingIds: [],
    _id: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e4,
    username: 'user0',
    email: 'email0@email.com',
    password: '$2a$10$vWAeJJ1blfCJOyAVrAN7c.a5e9HOFyU21GfQCkvbNTD3uC0lMgkta',
    name: 'Mrs. Fae Koelpin',
    bio: 'Repellat qui laudantium sed illum non corrupti optio. Sed perspiciatis ipsa nobis placeat tempore exercitationem rerum. 
Aut cupiditate omnis provident maxime reprehenderit laudantium.',
    avatarId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e2,
    coverId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e3,
    role: 'ADMIN',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    followersIds: [],
    followingIds: [ 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e4 ],
    _id: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e7,
    username: 'user1',
    email: 'email1@email.com',
    password: '$2a$10$enruHkMUkcw07T.vgxeEQ.BV0rJ7xKO7HwVYsqYRlM2Cl7y1oaLEa',
    name: 'Rasheed Hickle',
    bio: 'Distinctio dolorem asperiores deserunt debitis aut quia. Aut deleniti ea sit qui aliquid aperiam accusantium repellendus. Ut ut non nulla vel fugiat dolore.',
    avatarId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e5,
    coverId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e6,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    followersIds: [],
    followingIds: [ 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e4 ],
    _id: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968ea,
    username: 'user2',
    email: 'email2@email.com',
    password: '$2a$10$juU/iUHy8g1vqBXmZplP8uiR75BPNm9ZfOoTpbzzEvhzNARRBFpKe',
    name: 'Jillian Kassulke',
    bio: 'Consequuntur molestiae repellat alias ut quis. Voluptas qui consectetur sed numquam fugit. Illo repellendus sint.',     
    avatarId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e8,
    coverId: 5e36ffe2c1d67534241968e9,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: can you post `me` value please?

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: Can you post also sample of your `user` collection. It works https://mongoplayground.net/p/XdpFpiaAyJV . Btw: `{limit,}` is wrong, should be `{limit : limit}` (second limit has 10 value)

Comment: I posted users sample.

Comment: Maybe you're accidentally passing in `undefined` and you need to use `me._id`?

Comment: I am passing correct Id https://prnt.sc/qwh7hc . I found out what is the issue, I have cached data in Apollo client in React frontend part of my application from the first page when user is still not logged in. When I refresh the page user is correctly filtered out.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same thing! Would appreciate some help :) See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818739/how-to-use-mongodb-ne-on-nested-object-property

Answer (score 2):

Assume 'me' is an object which contains currant user information.Hence try to use just `me.id` in filter.

`{ _id: { $ne: me.id } }`

or

`{ _id: { $ne: ObjectId(me.id) } }`

Comment: I tried both and it is not working. However when I set `{ username: { $ne: me.username } }` it is working.