# How to use MongoDB $ne on nested object property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node API which connects to a mongoDB through mongoose. I am creating an advanced results middleware that enabled selecting, filtering, sorting, pagination etc. based on a Brad Traversy course [Node.js API Masterclass With Express & MongoDB](https://www.udemy.com/course/nodejs-api-masterclass/). This is all good.

I am adapting the code from the course to be able to use the $ne (not equal) operator and I want to be able to get a model that is not equal to a nested property (user id) of the model. I am using this for an explore feature to see a list of things, but I don't want to show the user their own things. I am having trouble figuring out how to access the id property.

********************* UPDATE *********************

It seems all the documentation I've read recommends writing const injected like this:

```
const injected = {
  'user._id': { "$ne": req.user.id }
};
```

but for some reason it is not working. I can query top level properties that are just a plain string value like this:

```
const injected = {
  access: { "$ne": "public" }
};
```

but not a property on an object. Does anyone know why? Is it because the property I want to query is an id? I've also tried:

```
const injected = {
  'user._id': { "$ne": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) }
};
```

which also does not work...

---

So the model looks like this:

```
{
  name: 'Awesome post',
  access: 'public',
  user: {
    _id: '2425635463456241345', // property I want to access
  }
}
```

then the actual advanced results middleware looks like this and it's the 'injected' object where I am trying to access id. In the course brad uses this syntax to use lte (/?averageCost[lte]=10000) but I do not get any results with my ne. Can anyone help me here?

```
const advancedResults = (model, populate) => async (req, res, next) => {
  let query;

  const injected = {
      access: 'public',
      'user._id[ne]': req.user.id,  // I don't think user._id[ne] is correct
    };
  }

  // Copy req.query
  const reqQuery = { ...req.query, ...injected };

  console.log('injected: ', injected);


  // Fields to exclude
  const removeFields = ['select', 'sort', 'page', 'limit'];

  // Loop over removeFields and delete them from reqQuery
  removeFields.forEach(param => delete reqQuery[param]);

  // Create query string
  let queryStr = JSON.stringify(reqQuery);

  // Create operators ($gt, $gte, etc)
  queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte|in|ne)\b/g, match => `$${match}`);


  // Finding resource and remove version
  query = model.find(JSON.parse(queryStr)).select('-__v');

  // Select Fields
  if (req.query.select) {
    const fields = req.query.select.split(',').join(' ');
    query = query.select(fields);
  }

  // Sort
  if (req.query.sort) {
    const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
    query = query.sort(sortBy);
  } else {
    query = query.sort('-createdAt');
  }

  // Pagination
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;
  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10) || 25;
  const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
  const endIndex = page * limit;
  const total = await model.countDocuments(JSON.parse(queryStr));

  query = query.skip(startIndex).limit(limit);

  if (populate) {
    query = query.populate(populate);
  }

  // Executing query
  const results = await query;

  // Pagination result
  const pagination = {};

  if (endIndex < total) {
    pagination.next = {
      page: page + 1,
      limit,
    };
  }

  if (startIndex > 0) {
    pagination.prev = {
      page: page - 1,
      limit,
    };
  }

  res.advancedResults = {
    success: true,
    count: results.length,
    pagination,
    data: results,
  };

  next();
};

module.exports = advancedResults;
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question about how to use `$ne`:

The use of [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) is as follows:

```js
"field":{
  "$ne": yourValue
}
```

Into your query should be like:

```js
"user._id": {
  "$ne": req.user.id
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qKmhADQeV_Y)

`$ne` operator will return all document where the field value don't match with the given value.

As you have done, to acces the nested field is necessary use the dot notation.

Also, to ensure it works, if your schema defines `_id` as `ObjectId` maybe is necessary parse `req.user.id` to `ObjectId`.
But if in your schema is a string then should works.

So try (not tested at all):

```js
const injected = {
  'user._id': { "$ne": req.user.id }
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It does not seem to be working though; I still get results from the logged in user. I've also tried replacing req.user.id with a hard coded string.

Comment: I also tried it like this: 'user._id': { ne: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) }, with no luck. (I removed the $ from ne because if you notice my code will add that later.

Comment: Can you post your `req` object?

Comment: The entire request or just the query? A console log of the queryStr after I create the operators gives (the id here is fake): queryStr:  {"access":"public","user._id":{"$ne":"5t845tu495t83r3iuf3rf"}}

Comment: Your query is looking for `access:"public"` but your model only have fields `name` and `user`. I've used `name:"Awesome post"` instead of `"access":"public"` and it works. If your data or your model has changed edit the OP and I will execute again.

Comment: Sorry, I did not post the ACTUAL model in my question, but yes there is a property on the actual model to say whether the thing (its also not a post) has public or private access. I have updated the OP but I had already tested the access and I had that working.

Comment: I've executed the model with `populate = false` and works. Into your mongoose schema, what is the type of `user._id`?

Comment: The user is of type Schema.Types.ObjectId

Comment: It seems that user._id is being sent as a string rather than a property, Could this be the issue? _conditions: { access: 'public', 'user._id': { '$ne': '5fae47381a6ce23291234bbe' } },

Comment: Try to set `id` like this: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(yourStringId)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224523/discussion-between-j-f-and-cbutler).

Comment: It seems dot notation is not working here. All the answers I've looked at recommend the following syntax: 'user._id': { "$ne": req.user.id } but for some reason it is not working. My query returns all the results and does not filter.